# Can i use solr by itself

Tags: apache, solr, nutch

I'm building a search engine and need to crawl the web, index it and be able to search the data.

Can I use Apache Solr by itself or do I need Nutch first to crawl the web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a crawler to gather the content, so Solr can index it. [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) and [Crawl Anywhere](http://www.crawl-anywhere.com/) work well with Solr.

Answer (score 1):

Solr is an indexer and Nutch is a Crawler!
They can NOT do each others job!
If you want to have a search engine you have to have a crawler and an indexer!
you can change them or even you can create your own application for this!